# Jenkins Pipeline sh command producing java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.regex.Matcher

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, aws-cli

I have a pipeline that executes many `sh` (shell) commands against AWS. All of them work without issue, except fo this one. Originally I was just running the `sh` command directly, but I ended up wrapping it in the try block to debug.

```
            def instanceip = instance_details =~ /PrivateIpAddress.*(10[0-9.]*)/
            if ((instanceip)) {
                INSTANCEIP = instanceip.group(1)
                println "INSTANCE_IP=$INSTANCEIP"
            }
            def instanceid = instance_details =~ /InstanceId.*(i-[0-9a-f]*)/
            if ((instanceid)) {
                INSTANCEID = instanceid.group(1)
                println "INSTANCE_ID=$INSTANCEID"
            }

            try {
                shellCommand = "aws ec2 terminate-instances --region ${args.awsRegion} --instance-ids $INSTANCEID"
                println "executing: ${shellCommand}"
                sh "${shellCommand}"
            } catch (NotSerializableException err) {
                println "${err}"
            }
```

I have confirmed that the `sh` command is valid and it even runs, but for some unknown reason it produces `java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.regex.Matcher`. Here are the relevant logs from my pipeline:

```
[Pipeline] echo
executing: aws ec2 terminate-instances --region us-west-2 --instance-ids i-0392802baaadca13d
[Pipeline] sh
+ aws ec2 terminate-instances --region us-west-2 --instance-ids i-0392802baaadca13d
{
    "TerminatingInstances": [
        {
            "InstanceId": "i-0392802baaadca13d", 
            "CurrentState": {
                "Code": 32, 
                "Name": "shutting-down"
            }, 
            "PreviousState": {
                "Code": 0, 
                "Name": "pending"
            }
        }
    ]
}
[Pipeline] echo
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.regex.Matcher
```

Just like the other `aws` calls, this appears to return a very normal JSON document as plain text.

I did get the instance ID using a regex, but have confirmed that it is a string, and it obviously renders into the string I give to `sh`. Why is the result of running this `sh` command producing this exception?

Comment: Could you please post the code involving the regexp up until the fatal error? That is the code producing the exception.

Comment: I got this working by using installing the Pipeline Utility Steps `readJSON` command https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace. I have edited to show my regex anyway.

Comment: `readJSON` is indeed a serializable method. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: How are you using the other sh commands? Can you try this way: 
sh (
    script: "${shellCommand}",
    returnStdout: true
)

Comment: @DanielPeña I did try that, but I got the same error.

Comment: Good, and if you try putting the $INSTANCEID inside a String: "aws ec2 terminate-instances --region ${args.awsRegion} --instance-ids '$INSTANCEID'".

Answer (score 0):

the problem in lines like

```
def instanceid = instance_details =~ /InstanceId.*(i-[0-9a-f]*)/
```

and you are using the `instanceid` variable (that is actually Matcher) only in `if` on the next line.

just put your regexp match into `if`.

```
if (instance_details =~ /InstanceId.*(i-[0-9a-f]*)/){...
```